# ship cloudwatch metrics across account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

we have a multiple account setup in aws. Apps A,B,C are deployed into their own accounts. I want to export cloudwatch metrics (only metrics not logs) into monitoring-account (say) so that I can monitor and keep a tab on it

I have tried googling but couldnt find anything. please help

Answer (score 1):

AWS recently announced a feature to enable cross account access of CloudWatch Metrics. Step by step instructions can be see at the following url:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Cross-Account-Cross-Region.html

Answer (score 0):

Centralized logging is an important requirement for various purposes such as logging, compliance, etc. It is also a recommendation form AWS to aggregate your logs in a separate account. But it requires a bit of work and understand how it all works. Here is an official AWS blog giving you step by step approach.

[AWS Centralized Logging blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/stream-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-to-a-centralized-account-for-audit-and-analysis/)

Comment: Thanks Juned. I have an idea about logs aggregation. however, this question is only related to metrics.

Answer (score 0):

using cloudwatch agent config, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html
credentials param can be supplied with the cross account role arn.
Thanks,